# Get Username/SID of the Owner of a process - Powershell/Python

Tags: python, powershell, process

I'm looking to get **JUST** the username of the owner of a process, not in a list, array or table. I need it completely by itself so when I store the output in a variable, it is **ONLY** the username. (An SID instead of a username will also suffice) This has to work in Powershell 2.0 or Python 2.*. I'm still fairly new to both powershell and python so working examples are greatly appreciated, and if it helps, explorer.exe is the process I want to find the username of the owner for. Also, I need to run the command/script provided as an answer under the SYSTEM context.(You can provide your answer either completely in python or completely in powershell, it does not matter for what I am doing)

P.S. Windows Only :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [`psutil`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) seems like a good choice for this:

```
import psutil

pid = 1
username = psutil.Process(pid).username

print "Process {} is owned by {}".format(pid, username)
```

On Linux the result is:

```
Process 1 is owned by root
```

Comment: I might be a bit silly in the head and forgot to mention I am doing this on Windows. (Does powershell give it away?) Anyway, will it work on Windows and is there anyway to get the pid of a process by name. So for example, convert explorer.exe to a pid and then use your method to get the owner.

Comment: Yes, the code I've listed works on Windows. I tested on Linux because that's all that I use, but `psutil` is described as cross-platform. There may be ways to look up processes by the name of the executable, but you won't get a unique mapping. There could potentially be multiple processes named `explorer.exe`.

Comment: You might want to follow the `psutil` link in my answer and see if it provides a solution for process-name-to-PID lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Answer accepted above, I know, but for future reference:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter 'Name = "explorer.exe"' | ForEach-Object { $_.GetOwner() }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not just print out the username, but other output too which is not what I wanted. (Unless there is a way to cut it down to just the username)

Comment: Change it to  `$_.GetOwner().user` for just the user.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your input Ben. With the .user on the end it is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: Is there any way I can store the output in a variable? It doesn't seem to be working for me.